# Why is Xcode not prefixing filenames?

Tags: xcode

When I start an iOS single view application project, the AppDelegate files and ViewController files are not prefixing with the project name like they used to.

files names are as follows when I open a new project:

*AppDelegate.h* 
 *AppDelegate.m* 
 *MainStoryBoard.storyboard* 
 *ViewController.h* 
 *ViewController.m*

Why is this?

Comment: But where is the problem?

Comment: XCode 5? Are you defining the class prefix property when creating a new project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to add it manually. When you create a new project just fill out the "Class Prefix" field on the screen where you name the project/bundle id/ etc..

Just add your prefix where I wrote "THIS IS THE PREFIX" in the screenshot below

[image]

If you want to add a prefix after you've created your project, you can do so in the file inspector on Xcode's right pane:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add a prefix after the project is created?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. I believe it will only apply to classes created from that point out though.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I prefer not to prefix class names within an application.

When you are writing code for libraries, or custom classes, or categories, they are recommended, as there aren't namespaces in Objective-C.

But for application classes, I find they are just noise. Looking down a list of files that all have the same three letters in the front makes it just a bit harder to find what I'm looking for.

I mean, are you really going to have more than one class called AppDelegate? I'm all for full and descriptive naming of my classes, but prefixes for all the classes doesn't help me.

If it helps there are a few conventions for writing code. Search and you'll find them. [Here are mine](http://abizern.org/cocoa-coding-conventions/), for example.

You don't have to follow them, but pick a style and be consistent with it.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 8 does NOT have the 'Class Prefix' field. It only has 'Product Name' and this does not ripple down to the view controller or the app delegate. I think 8.3 has bugs.

Comment: VectorVictor is correct-- Just tested on Xcode 8.3.3. I don't think its a bug however. I think Xcode has just stopped offering this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Class Prefix is file & template business. For the sake of organised files in a project it makes sense to have filenames that express their contents.
The workflow to achieve that was actually simplified with the Class Prefix field in the File inspector panel while your project name is active (clicked) in the file browser.

When there is a class prefix set the class name field when creating new files is predefined. That way you can choose file by file (class by class) if you want to use it and class name and file name will result in similar name scheme.
[image]