# Class Prefix missing in project template in Xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode6.1

There used to be a class prefix field on project template, which would help distinguish project classes with framework classes. This is no longer available in Xcode 6.1 project templates. What is the intension behind this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to some sources Apple removed this intentionally. They are no longer encouraging the use of prefixes for app code, with the reasoning that app code will not be reused and therefore will have little chance of name conflicts. See: http://scottberrevoets.com/2014/07/25/objective-c-prefixes-a-thing-of-the-past/

They are encouraging it only if you are developing a framework. For frameworks, you can add it using project inspector: 
[Why is Xcode not prefixing filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149887/why-is-xcode-not-prefixing-filenames)

I use the above method to add prefixes to my app code because I find it neater. Also if some framework I end up using doesn't follow the prefix convention, I can be sure there won't be a name conflict with my code.

Comment: `"I use the above method to add prefixes to my app code"` What above method is that ? :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is my experience about renaming filenames (Xcode v6.3):

1. Create the project with name Hello:

   2.Project Hello is created. 
   Start renaming files in Navigator 
   and in source code - add prefix Hello:
2. Then you have to change class name in Interface Builder source code:
   RightClick on MainStoryboard -> Open As -> Source Code
3. Find in source classname and add prefix Hello:

   NB! Ops I forgot to change names in main.m file - add prefix Hello to AppDelegate: